# Discovering cookie session data

Tags: cookies

Can anyone advice me on how I can discover the active cookie details for a user logged into a Drupal website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cookie data is in the PHP superglobal $_COOKIE.  However a typical Drupal site only stores the a random session identifier in the cookie, so it may not be what you're looking for.  If $_COOKIE doesn't answer your question please post more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The session ID in the active cookie is a key to many things which you may think of as part of the cookie, even though they're stored on the server. You may want to look at $_SESSION as well.